# Физически удален хостинг

Tags: хостинг

Доброго времени суток. Сегодня захожу на свой некий сайт и вижу следующее *Данный домен зарегистрирован в интересах клиента.*

Зашел в билинг панель хостера и вижу что заказанного мною хостинга **физически** не существует. Пропали труды 3-х месячной работы над проектом.

На почте хранится куча сообщений о заказе услуги, ее продлению и т.п.

Кто сталкивался с подобным ранее? Какие мне принимать меры по произошедшему и т.д.

Хочу услышать ваши советы и прочее.

**UPD**

*Администраторы уже занимаются решением данной проблемы. В ближайшее время работа аккаунта будет восстановлена.
Приносим извинения за доставленные неудобства.*

Жду)

Comment: Есть такие волшебные слова: "бэкап", "дамп", "тестовый сервер" и "SVN"... Произносящие их регулярно никогда не жалуются на пропажи :)

Comment: Это все хорошо, но в документах хостера красноречиво написано - *3.1.6. Исполнитель не имеет права вмешиваться в деятельность Заказчика по поводу его работы в пределах предоставленных Услуг, кроме случаев, предусмотренных законодательством Украины.*

Comment: Кто хостер? Пусть страна знает своих героев.

Comment: С волшебным словом `git` и сервисом bitbucket.org появляется бесплатная возможность хранить копию всех ревизий исходников сайта, что тоже неплохо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ну если есть доказательства на почте, смело пиши им и звони!

Если пойдут на попятную, смело подавай в суд, распечатывай материалы с почты - тогда они запоют другую песню.

//upd

Сначала позвони в саппорт, если в саппорте тебя мягко говоря пошлют, проси старшего по саппорту, если и он такой же тугой, тогда если хостер в твоем городе смело едь к ним!
Приедишь к ним, в руках у тебя уже должна быть бумага в 2х экземплярах о том что случилось и что ты хочешь в этом разобраться! один они берут себе, на втором ставят приходный номер и  печать, и ФИО того кто принял заявление. в течении времени они обязаны ответить тебе.

Можешь распечатать в свое доказательство письма с почты, причем в заголовках писем есть от кого отправлено вплоть до IP.

Думаю они быстро решат проблему, иначе 1 отзыв в нете может ой как пагубно отразиться на всем хостере!

[[@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan)](/users/3526/palmervan)  если есть доказательства на почте, смело разговаривай с ними на тон выше, чем обычно. Не навязывай им то что ты прав, а говори это! Если они не тупые пойдут на встречу и все сделают, если тупые -суд и они станут еще тупее.

//upd

физически удалить все равно его проблематично в плане бекапов. т.е. тут дело в чем, если пропали данные только у тебя - то дело пахнет керосином, если у 100 клиентов такое же то тут беда вселенского масштаба - но тоже подпадает под нарушение со стороны хостера. А ежели только твой аккаунт - тогда вопрос встанет иначе что они руками искоренили акк + всю инфу и дампы - а это еще +1 в твою карму и выигрыш дела на суде.

Comment: Хочу только добавить, что похожая проблема встречалась у моего коллеги. Хостер ломался не долго, когда дело запахло судом. В итоге - компенсация 1500 зелени и пять лет бесплатного хоста. **НО** бэкапы и дампы сайта, у него естественно все были сохранены )) Поэтому мораль: @klopp прав по поводу резервный хранений, но поиметь с недобросовестного хостера - святое дело.

Comment: Пока веду переписку с ними, туговато отвечают. Сейчас пойду с юристом на работе побакланю еще!

Comment: Да, т.к. тут нарушение правил со стороны хостера, денег да можно поиметь много, поверьте на слово. Такое было с питерским хостером одним и у меня. Погубили 4 сайта, и 3 месяца их неработоспособности(судебное разбирательство), и как итог куча денег на рекламу вылетело в трубу у одного из клиентов. а там суммы были не 1,5К зелени \+ завал посещаемости сайта. А это красивая сумма денег.

Comment: @Shrek, а откуда 3 месяца? При наличии бэкапа сайт разворачивается в течении суток-двух (учитывая возню с регистрацией на другом хостинге и прочухивание DNS). Месяцы, даже недели - это сильно постараться надо :)

Comment: @klopp написал же **(судебное разбирательство)** т.к. все бекапы были у хостера и до окончания разбирательства не могли быть перенесены. т.к. изначально их не было, они как бы испарились, а потом нашлись после первых нескольких слушаний, ну и т.д.

Comment: А, ну если бэкапы в том же месте делать - это и называется "сильно постараться" :-)

Comment: Ну тогда это были не мои проекты и я ими не занимался, по этому бекапы делал хостер и у себя же их хранил.

Answer (score 0):

Надо садиться на уши хостеру и ездить ему же по мозгам. Скорее всего, что-то слетело у них. И, если повезло, найдутся бэкапы и всё восстановят.

Comment: Не тут не на уши нужно капать а предоставить данные с почты и в случае если не восстановят - судебное дело, которое будет выиграно!